# How to delete chrome bookmarks in all devices?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I use chrome with my google account on several devices (Windows and Android), adding bookmarks works fine (I add it on one device and it shows up in all my devices), but deleting them, not so much.

Is there a way to delete a bookmark "from the cloud" so that it gets deleted across all my devices?

I saw somewhere a recommendation about using Google Docs for this, but this approach does not seem to be working anymore.

Comment: If you are syncing your bookmarks then when you do a sync it will remove the bookmark

Comment: @Ramhound That is what I expected it to do, however it does not seem to be the case. It goes as far as adding it back on the device I just deleted it when I logoff and logon again. I have tried this on several devices (Android 2.x, Android 4.x, Windows 7 and 8.1) with not luck.

Answer (score 0):

This feature now works as expected since Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 (or maybe earlier, but this is the one I tested).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the problem can still occur as of Chrome 67.  While they have solved the problem generically, it's a reoccurring problem if you use any tools that delete and regenerate bookmarks automatically (such as external bookmark sync plugins). It doesn't detect the delete commands the plugins generate and they don't get synced.